# Does a Python-like virtualenv exist in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a Python-like virtualenv environment simulator for Julia where one can do development in a local, virtual environment?

Comment: I haven't come across anything like python's virtualenv, but you might be able to accomplish what you're looking for by setting the JULIA_PKGDIR environment variable.  Have a look at what it does in the docs: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/pkg/?highlight=julia_pkgdir.

Comment: @Chisholm [This](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) is virtualenv, the one I have included as an example in the question

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I meant to say that I haven't come across anything like python's virtualenv for Julia.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Currently (julia 1.2) is able to manage virual environments via it's builtin `Pkg` standard library module:

- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg

```
julia> ]

(v1.2) pkg> activate tutorial
[ Info: activating new environment at `/tmp/tutorial/Project.toml`.

(tutorial) pkg>

(tutorial) pkg> status
    Status `/tmp/tutorial/Project.toml`
   (empty environment)

(tutorial) pkg> add Example
...

(tutorial) pkg> status
    Status `/tmp/tutorial/Project.toml`
  [7876af07] Example v0.5.1
```

<s>There is [`Playground.jl`](https://github.com/Rory-Finnegan/Playground.jl)</s>

> <s>A package for managing julia sandboxes like python's virtualenv (with a little influence from pyenv and virtualenvwrapper)</s>

Comment: This answer should probably be no longer considered the best answer as i believe the best practice is to generate virtual environments through the standard library.

Answer (score 21):

Nowadays Julia has this built into its package manager. They're called [environments](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/environments/). It boils down to this:

1. Enter the package mangement REPL by hitting `]`
2. Use the command `activate $dir` to switch to the environment described in `$dir`
3. Use the command `instantiate` to install the packages described in the environment

Comment: You can find a more in depth description here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/#Environments-1

Answer (score -3):

What's wrong with just having a *separate* Julia installation in another directory? Then you just need to set the JULIA_PKGDIR environment variable appropriately, for the Julia setup you want to run.

Comment: **That** you need to manually set the environment variable. Delegate this responsibility.